# IBpy - getting my market position

Tags: python-3.5, ibpy

Lets assume i have only one position in my IB account.
To retrieve it, I run the below:

```
from time import sleep
from ib.opt import Connection, message, ibConnection
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract

def acc_update(msg):
    global acc, expiry, exch, pExch, secType, symbol
    acc = msg.account
    exch = msg.contract.m_exchange
    pExch = msg.contract.m_primaryExch
    secType = msg.contract.m_secType
    expiry = msg.contract.m_expiry
    symbol = msg.contract.m_symbol
    return acc, expiry, exch, pExch, secType, symbol


tws = ibConnection(port= 7497)
tws.register(acc_update, message.position) 
tws.connect()
tws.reqPositions()
sleep(0.5)
tws.disconnect()
print( [symbol, acc, expiry, exch, pExch, secType])
```

this gives me:
['BAC', 'DUC00074', '20170519', None, '', 'OPT']

- Why aren't the exchange and the primary_exchange data showing ?

Comment: My guess is IB doesn't store the information.  It's actually useless to know where you bought it for the purpose of knowing what you have.

Comment: ok, thought the info was available; after all the opening order was initiated with IB too.  
Debating on the use of knowing it depends how many positions etc. The idea being to be able to close or add positions by directing the fields feed of the position directly to a new order.

Comment: You can but just make the exchange "SMART", that way it will try and route to the exchange with the best price.